# semantically understanding recursive reverse string return statement

Tags: java, recursion

Currently Im getting familiar with recursion and in trying to achieve further understanding i wanted to look at it in the context of reversing Strings. I know its not as efficient as using the StringBuffer but like i said this is mainly to help get a better understanding. I know there are a few questions on SO regarding this but i would just like some help with the walkthrough.

```
                 return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

String in this scenario = "Start"

I know that the substring method is taking a substring without the first character

the recursive calls. (partial)

```
reverse("Start")
reverse("tart")
reverse("art")
reverse("rt")
reverse("t") // when string is 1 char length then the reverse string is returned
```

But I would like some insight into how it concatenates and rebuilds the string in the recursive walkthrough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement

```
return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

is saying "reverse the last n-1 characters and move the first character to the end" (where the string has length n). This makes sense if you think about it trace the recursive calls through:

```
reverse("tart") + "S"
(reverse("art") + "t") + "S"
((reverse("rt") + "a") + "t") + "S"
(((reverse("t") + "r") + "a") + "t") + "S"
((((reverse("") + "t") + "r") + "a") + "t") + "S"
```

Assuming a suitable stopping condition when you are left with an empty string, the method calls now return one by one:

```
(((("t") + "r") + "a") + "t") + "S"
((("tr") + "a") + "t") + "S"
(("tra") + "t") + "S"
("trat") + "S"
"tratS"
```

Comment: Good answer but I would always return the empty string when the `length()` is zero (empty string). You don't want to test for a null string.

Comment: Thanks Pixel. Thats exactly what i needed. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

For recursion its best to think in terms of having a base case and a recursive call.

I assume you have something like:

```
public String reverse(String str){
    if (str.length() == 0) 
         return str;

    return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

The return call at the end is just taking the first character from the string and concatenating it to the recursive call of `reverse`. So the first character of the progressively shorter string always gets appended to the end of the string i.e. getting reversed.

Instead of thinking of each stage of the recursion, its best to just look at the base case and recursive call. Using a process of induction you can be sure that the recursion will work.

Actually I think it would be easier in this case to start with a string with 3 characters e.g "str" to see whats going on. If it works for that it will work for all cases (this is induction).